# Utilizing mini-pci bluetooth card from laptop as a transmitter

Tags: bluetooth

Would it be possible (if the traces can be identified) to use a blutooth card from a laptop to transmit data from an arduino to say a phone.

I know the arduino to phone part will work, I am just unsure if I can use a laptop bluetooth card in  such a manner

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing which laptop bluetooth card, we can't answer. Chances are if it's a Dell that they use the BC4 (BlueCore IV) chipset, which is very well documented and hacker friendly.

An alternative is to use a breakout board such as [this one](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=324).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's wired to the USB, which would make it difficult.

Try to identify the chip(set) and/or how it's wired on the laptop. If it's not a dead laptop, you should be able to look at the buses and see where it appears and as what type.